# Using dbcontext in .net core application

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am running .net core application as windows services. So my question is how can I use the dbcontext in windows service for database operations?

Below is Service Class

```
public class SendMailHostService : WebHostService
{
    private readonly EventLog _log = new EventLog("Application") { Source = "Application" };
    public SendMailHostService(IWebHost host) : base(host)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnStarted()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Asp.net service started.");
        Console.ReadLine();     
    }

    protected override void OnStarting(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Asp.net service starting.");
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
}
```

and service extension class:

```
public static class SendMailHostServiceExtensions
{
    public static void RunAsSendMailService(this IWebHost host)
    {
        var webHostService = new SendMailHostService(host);
        webHostService.ServiceName = "LMS.WinService.SendEmail";
        ServiceBase.Run(webHostService);
    }
}
```

Do I need to inject the dependency in service class?
Edit:1
Initially I need to connect to Client management database in which a table called Clientsconnectionstring will have the connection string of all clients and after that I need to create db context for each of clients and execute windows service logic.

Comment: It's Your choice if You use injection or not. so NO - You do NOT have to. but You may do that if You so choose

Comment: I have edited my question,  can you please update on it ?

Comment: there's a difference in "How do I" and "How can I".. it's broad.. the answers are going to be generic.. and if they get specific, they will probably be scrutinized.. do a little research, then ask questions that invoke answers that the community can substantiate. with that said, Do you have a class library csproj? do you have any sort of Domain Driven Design going?

Comment: No class library project,  I am running core application as windows service

Comment: If I configure management connection string in startup.cs can create context from that in this case ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the context on demand in each method you need it.

Comment: It's not that easy, as he'd need to access the configuration for it, which you can't easily do in an extension method which doesn't extend ServiceProvider or has access to the configuraton object w/o falling to anti-patterns like singletons or service locator pattern

Comment: What kind of configuration?

Comment: I have edited my question, can you please update on it ?